# RegEx match quotes with 1 or more results

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx that matches the following

```
"Field1":"Any Content"
```

But not this

```
"Field1":""
```

I've tried

```
"Field1":".*?"
```

But it finds matches for ""

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What language or tool are you writing the regex in?

Comment: Am using the .Net RegEx class

Comment: The C# .Net RegEx Class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your zero-or-more quantifier (`*`) to a one-or-more quantifier (`+`):

```
"Field1":".+?"
```

You may also want to consider using a character class, like this:

```
"Field1":"[^"]+"
```

Comment: This should be sufficient no? "Field1":".+" omit the "?"

Comment: @Khan That can lead to unexpected results if the match appears twice in the input string--e.g. `"Field1":"foo","Field1":"bar"`. The non-greedy quantifier limits the match to as small a result string as necessary to satisfy the match.

Comment: @pswg Ahh I see, didn't see the usefulness of the greedy part. But it is a good point if that case should appear.