# Regex matching optional quoted string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match an optional quoted string of the form, odd number of quotes are invalid string.

`"the quick brown fox" abc def` matches `the quick brown fox`

and

```
the quick brown fox abc def
```

return the whole string

I found this which comes very close 
[matching optional quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568995/how-do-i-match-a-pattern-with-optional-surrounding-quotes)

So I tired the following  `^(")?(.*)(?(1)\1|)`

but then unmatched quotes become valid which is no good.

EDIT

If the input string starts with a " then find the closing quote and return the string in the quotes. If quotes not matched return nothing. If the string does not start with a " then return the whole string.

This comes close I think ..

```
^(")?([^"]+)(?(1)\1|$)
```

Thanks for the various comments - this does what I'm looking for

```
^(")?([^"]+\w)(?(1)\1|$)
```

Comment: Which programming language are you trying to accomplish this in? Additionally, what should be done with e.g. `"the quick brown fox" abc "def` ?

Comment: c# - have edited the question to make it a little clearer I hope.

Comment: Make it lazy then: [**`^(["'])?(.*?)(?(1)\1|.+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/sf2aRi/1/) - is this what you're after?

Comment: unfortunately that allows unmatched quotes.

Comment: Can there be escaped quotes as well like `"abc \"foo"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match quotes with 1 or more results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201913/regex-match-quotes-with-1-or-more-results)

Answer (score 1):

```
"(?:"|.)*?"|^[^"]*$
```

First part catches quoted texts only, the second part catches entieres lines without quotes.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I need to return the quoted string without the quotes. Would be great if I can make sure the last character before the closing quote is not white space and not punctuation.

Comment: You can use brakects to catch the text and a optional token for ending non-word characters : ```"((?:"|.)*?)\W*"```. Just get the first catch group (\1).

Comment: `(?:"|.)*?"` is equivalent to `.*?"`

Comment: Also I'd say its easier to just trim the quotes off of the resulting match. Using capture groups will require a logic check to see if `\1` contains anything